# Image not found or type unknown con DOMPDF en PHP

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

necesito mostrar una imagen en un PDF que es generado por DOMPDF.

```
<img src="./../img/55.png" alt="">
```

Ese es la imagen que voy a mostrar

```
$html = ob_get_clean();
require_once('./../../librerias/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$domPDF = new Dompdf();

$domPDF->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$domPDF->set_option('isRemoteEnabled', true);
//$options = $dompdf->getOptions();
$domPDF->loadHTML($html);
$domPDF->render();
$pdf = $domPDF->output();
file_put_contents("./../PDF/imagen.pdf",$pdf);
```

Al inicio del documento el ob_start(); el pdf funciona bien, pero la imagen aparece con el error Image not found or type unknown

Comment: Hola, ¿instalaste DOMPDF via **composer** o manualmente?

Comment: Si, voy a borrar la pregunta porque ya conseguí la respuesta, la clave era pasar las imágenes a base64

Comment: Recomiendo que documentes tu respuesta, para que en un futuro las demás personas obtengan una respuesta a esta pregunta.